# AWS keyboard - how to prevent holding Shift or Ctrl to be interpreted as repeted pressing of the key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, centos

I started using AWS Linux (CentOS) but I have problem in IntelliJ Idea: holding the Shift or Ctrl keys pressed is interpreted as repeated press of that key and consequently a pop up shows up that would show up when pressing the key 2 times. 
How can this be fixed?

Edit: I'm using IntelliJ Idea 2019.1.3 although this seems to be an OS issue, interpreting holding down keys Shift or Ctrl as repeated key strokes.

Comment: What IDE version do use? Could you please provide information from "Help | About"

Comment: It is Intellij Idea 2019.1.3

Comment: What JDK is used to run IDE?

Comment: I'm using Oracle JDK 1.8.0_191... Do you think this is related to jdk? I suspected it is an OS problem, genereting key-pressed event when it shouldn't... I also looked how to disable the keyboard shorcuts for 3xShift and 3xCtrl in Idea but I didn't find how to do it...

Comment: There are no 3xShift and 3xCtrl shortcuts in Idea. Please try to switch to JetBrains SDK: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

Comment: These shortcuts are there since 2017 I think, so in my version I have them

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE? What actions are activate by these shortcuts?

Comment: You were right, the shortcuts are 2xShift or Ctrl, not 3x... I corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did in the end was disable the 2xShift/Ctrl shortcuts

> 1. Open Find Action... ("Ctrl-Shift-A" on Windows and Linux, "Cmd-Shift-A" on macOS)
> 2. Type "Registry...", press Enter
> 3. Find the key ide.suppress.double.click.handler (just start typing for speed searching) and enable it

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161094

Comment: Thank you, this was maddening